# Adding new rows that contain identities, defaults via SQL Server Management Studio GUI

Tags: sql-server

In Enterprise Manager (SQL Server 2000-), you can add new rows to an existing table by right-clicking the table and selecting "Open Table". You get an MS Access-like grid with a single blank row at the bottom for adding new rows.

In Management Studio (SQL Server 2008+), the same functionality is available by right-clicking and selecting "Edit Top 200 Rows".

In the old Enterprise Manager version, any untouched columns are set with either their default value or new identity (if applicable). This happens as soon as focus leaves the row.

In Management studio, any values not explicitly typed-in are set to NULL (even if NULL is not allowed for the column). After focus leaves the row, there is a little exclamation icon to the left of the row with this tooltip:

"This row was successfully committed to the database. However, a problem occurred when attempting to retrieve the data back after the commit. Because of this, the data in this row is read-only. To fix this problem, please re-run the query."

Is there a setting somewhere to enable the old behavior? Or, is there a keyboard shortcut (similar to CTRL+0 == NULL) to indicate you want to use the default?

I feel like I must be missing something obvious--otherwise this view is pretty useless for quickly adding new rows.

Comment: I know of no way to change the behavior. That view is pretty useless for adding new rows anyway. Write an insert statement in a query window.

Comment: I feel pretty silly for not noticing this sooner, but I'll leave this question up with the answer in case someone else did the same thing I did...

I've always immediately deleted the row as soon as that icon shows up since the data looks bad. It turns out if you follow the tooltip instructions and actually re-run the query, the returned row DOES get the correct defaults, identity, etc.

The GUI behavior of showing an error and not immediately filling-in the columns seems really broken compared to the old Enterprise Manager way, but knowing the data is ok, I guess it is a non-issue.

Comment: This could happen if a duplicate row is inserted when there is no primary key, or did you find out any other reason?

Comment: @ThejakaMaldeniya - the table in question would not have had any other users adding data and the behavior is consistent on every insert. It just seems to be how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this behavior only happens when SQL Management Studio is connected to a SQL 2000 database. When editing rows on a SQL 2012 database the primary key immediately updates and there is no error icon. I think the best workaround is to just continue to use Enterprise Manager if you need to make quick edits on SQL 2000 databases.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the "to fix this problem please rerun the query" just right click on the read only row with the error and select "! Execute SQL".

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not management studio
this will take place even on a front end application
the issue is having identity column in a table
for some reason this behavior started when SQL 2012 came to life

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).